# EF Core Migrations Target Production Despite ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, environment-variables, database-migration

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project and facing an issue with Entity Framework Core migrations. I need to perform migrations in my development environment, but despite setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to Development, EF Core seems to be targeting the production environment.

I'm using the following command on macOS to set the environment variable:

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
dotnet ef migrations remove --verbose.
```

However, the EF Core command still attempts to open a connection to the production database (as indicated by the message: Opening connection to database 'I_STORE' on server 'mssqlshop'). This is the server name used in my production environment, not in development.

My appsettings.Development.json file contains the correct connection string for the development environment. I'm not sure why EF Core is not picking up the development settings.

Has anyone encountered this issue, or can you suggest what might be going wrong here? How can I ensure that EF Core targets the correct environment when performing migrations?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: If you're running migrations on a class library project (i.e. if your DbContext class is in a class lib, as opposed to a project targeting the Web SDK) you might want to try DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT instead of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

Comment: I tried setting the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT variable to Development and running the migrations, but it didn't work. I still get logs indicating that the connection is being made to the production database on the mssqlshop server. ```
Disposing connection to database 'I_STORE' on server 'mssqlshop'.
Disposed connection to database '' on server '' (1ms). ``` Also, modifying the configuration loading in Program.cs as suggested didn't help either. The application still seems to be using the production settings.

Comment: 1. Verify that `appsettings.json` is loaded correctly. 
```
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json");
```


2. Verify that `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is `Development`

   ```
   echo $ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
   ```